# How to change the default port of mysql from 3306 to 3360

Tags: mysql, sql, database, port

I want to change the default port number of MySQL server presently it is 3306. I want to change it to 3360.

I have tried:

```
-- port=3360
```

But things are not working for me. Please provide query to change port not any configuration. I am using Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: As you guessed right, this is not the right "forum" (and not a forum). Please consider asking your question on ServerFault.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to edit your `my.cnf` file and make sure you have the port set as in the following line:

```
port = 3360
```

Then restart your MySQL service and you should be good to go.  There is no query you can run to make this change because the `port` is not a dynamic variable (q.v. [here for MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html) showing a table of all system variables).

Comment: where is my.cnf file actually i am using mariadb which is fork of mysql

Comment: [This link to the MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/) will tell you where to find the `my.cnf` file.

Comment: Since you are running Windows, you can just so a file search for `my.cnf` on your `C:` drive to find it.

Comment: there is no my.cnf file but i found "my-huge.ini" containing port=3306 file can i modify it

Comment: `my-huge.ini` must be the config file for your MariaDB install.  Yes, modify it and then restart your database.

Comment: but my pc is not allowing to change it even after i changed all security constariants

Comment: Your MariaDB is running and it has a lock on the file.  You need to stop MariaDB from running, change the file, then start it again.

Comment: what is command to stop it i have tried "mysql.server stop" but not working

Comment: Not sure about MariaDB, but you could just kill the process from the task list (CTRL + ALT + DEL).

Comment: If you need to find "my.cnf" in Linux or the Windows Bash Console, type: `sudo find / -name "my.cnf"`

Answer (score 15):

If you're on Windows, you may find the config file `my.ini` it in this directory

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\
```

You open this file in a text editor and look for this section:

```
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```

Then you change the number of the port, save the file.
Find the service MYSQL57 under Task Manager > Services and restart it.

Comment: Section in ini file `[mysqld]`

Answer (score 13):

On newer (for example 8.0.0) the simplest solution is (good choice for a scripted start-up for example):

```
mysqld --port=23306
```

Comment: This answer should be upvoted. This whole database redefines the term "legacy" with its bugs and things that don't work and innovative futuristic features such as configuring via command line parameters are really welcome!

Answer (score 3):

When server first starts the `my.ini` may not be created where everyone has stated.  I was able to find mine in  `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`

This location has the defaults for every setting.

```
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

# pipe
# socket=0.0
port=4306  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Change this!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

[mysql]
no-beep

default-character-set=utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to installed mysql path and find bin folder,open my.ini and search 3306 after that change 3306 to 3360

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can just run the service using `/mysqld --PORT 1234`, it would force mysql to run on the specified port without change the cnf/ini file.

I just cought a case that cnf didn't work. It was weired... so I just use the cmd line as the shortcut and it works!

Answer (score 1):

In ***Windows 8.1 x64 bit*** os, Currently I am using **`MySQL`** version :

```
Server version: 5.7.11-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

For changing your `MySQL` port number, Go to installation directory, my installation directory is :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7
```

open the **`my-default.ini`** *Configuration Setting* file in any text editor.

search the line in the configuration file.

```
# port = .....
```

replace it with :

```
port=<my_new_port_number>
```

like my self changed to :

```
port=15800
```

**To apply the changes don't forget to immediate either restart the MySQL Server or your OS**.

Hope this would help many one.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the connection port to 8012

open xampp as administrator

Mysql config => my.ini change the port from 3306 to 8012

close and run it again
I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change `my.cnf` file and add this line or change it `port=3360`

at my fedora 34

```
sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
```

add This line ==> `port=3360`

Comment: This is the same answer as the accepted answer from 2015.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows and installed the database as a service, which is the default, you should find your configuration file by opening your services management console.
For instance: `win + r` and then type `services.msc`

Look for a service called MySQL or MariaDB.
On the general tab of the properties of this service you can find a path to your mysqld.exe file and the arguments to start the exe. The **--defaults-file** argument should point to your configuration file.

Edit your configuration file and restart the MySQL service.

Comment: Example: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this is take backup of required database and reconfigure the server.

**Creating A Backup**

The mysqldump command is used to create textfile “dumps” of databases managed by MySQL. These dumps are just files with all the SQL commands needed to recreate the database from scratch. The process is quick and easy.

If you want to back up a single database, you merely create the dump and send the output into a file, like so:

```
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

Multiple databases can be backed up at the same time:

```
mysqldump --databases database_one database_two > two_databases.sql
```

In the code above, database_one is the name of the first database to be backed up, and database_two is the name of the second.

It is also simple to back up all of the databases on a server:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

After taking the backup, remove mysql and reinstall it. After reinstalling with the desired port number.

**Restoring a Backup**

Since the dump files are just SQL commands, you can restore the database backup by telling mysql to run the commands in it and put the data into the proper database.

```
mysql database_name < database_name.sql
```

In the code above, database_name is the name of the database you want to restore, and database_name.sql is the name of the backup file to be restored..

If you are trying to restore a single database from dump of all the databases, you have to let mysql know like this:

```
mysql --one-database database_name < all_databases.sql
```

Comment: This is hardly the best way as it involves significant downtime, particularly if the database is large and dump/restore takes a long time. Also, reinstallation is not the same as reconfiguration.