# Mysql starts and stop

Tags: mysql

So I used mysql server in a project some time ago and everything worked fine. The server always started on start up and made it's updates. I used it with visual studio 2015. Now I want to use it again but it doesn't start anymore. When I start it manually it says that started and stopped because no service is using it. I reinstalled it but during the final steps when it says starting server it stays there until an error occurs. When I did the first project I was in another city and now I moved for a few week to another. I don't know if this is relevant but I read that changing the router may cause this.

Comment: Perhaps you have another process using the port.

Comment: have you seen the error log?

Comment: No, I can't find the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed IIS server or any other server that is using you port in your computer than this problem may arise. Sometimes it happens that your port is busy so whenever it tries to start to start MySql then it stops due to some reason.

You can change the port. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360)

If you are getting error in you apache server the you can change its port also from 80 to 8080.

Just edit httpd.conf file in your apache name folder there would be a folder named 'Conf' into that folder you will find httpd.conf file.

open with notepad or any text editor,

Press ctrl + H 
Put 80 into find column and 8080 into replace column then replace all.

Save the file.Now you're good to go.

Comment: I didn't install anything. When I try to change the port by reconfiguring the installation, after it asks me for the root password it freezes and then the installer isn't responding.

Comment: @ M. Jay Yeah. I changed the port and it works now. Many Thanks! But now I have other problem. Visual studio doesn't see mysql connection. I installed the connector and mysql for visual studio, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user6710 If you want to connect to MySql from visual studio you need to add Mysql.dll file into your project and then you have to import that library using 'Using' Command and there is other way you can connect use the following 2 links: [link1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html), [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW3uWewZrZQ)