# Can I use the same port on both MySQL Server and XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, port

Despites I've already installed XAMPP, I am trying to upload my database via MySQL server 5.7.17 since it's too big but both it and XAMPP use the same port - 3306. MySQL server is not even allowing me to continue to install it unless I make a change

SOrry, I'm a newbie.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Quvs.jpg)

Note It was suggested to me to download MySQL Server since I had already installed XAMPP but it didn't help me to upload my database.

Comment: It is called port and not door. A single port can only be used by a single program at a given time. If xampp has a mysql server installed, why do you want to install another one?

Comment: as I said, I'm newbie. I'm sorry I confuse the terms. It was suggested to me since I had already installed XAMPP but it didn't help me to upload my database.

Comment: XAMPP already comes with MySQL. It's refusing to install because that port is already in use by XAMPP's MySQL. You don't need two MySQL installations to "upload [your] database".

Comment: Actually my problem is that my database is big. I even changed phpMyAdmin to "wait" 10000 seconds, 0 second (no limit of time) but it didn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: For sure there's a way to configure one of you DB to listen on another port. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360 Maybe try to export and import your DB from the command line if you have acces to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line

Comment: @RyckRichards Don't use phpMyAdmin to upload a large database backup. Use the command line.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I tried but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @RyckRichards And "it doesn't work" means **what**, exactly?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not able to upload my database yet. I type mysql -u root -p tatoeba < tatoeba_database.sql and it don't work. The database is not imported.

Comment: @RyckRichards What *does* happen? Does it just sit there, or does it error out? How big is the import?

Comment: @ceejayoz - ~300Mb - I put that in my console and all I get is this: https://gist.github.com/RyckRichards/a925775223c3400a3b589d8fd5ada6f3

Answer (score 2):

No. If port 3306 is in use by an already installed and running MySQL instance, then *another* MySQL instance cannot use that same port.  It is possible to run MySQL on a port other than the default 3306. But before we go there...

I think we might be barking up the wrong tree, trying to install another copy of MySQL and to run two instances of MySQL.  Maybe we are wanting to run a different version of MySQL, other than the version other than what is included in the package we already installed.

But back pedal a bit here.

How is it that we reached the conclusion that installing another copy/version  of MySQL was a viable solution to the problem we encountered?

It seems like we want to figure out the *root cause* of the original problem, *before* we chase down the wrong rabbit trail...