# Can't connect to mysql when I changed its port number rather than 3306

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I kinda having an error when I tried to change mysql's port number to 9094 instead of 3306. But when I'm using 3306, I can get its data. I'm pretty sure I change all the port connection to my Java Web App from 3306 to 9094 but still having errors.

This is the error..

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

This is my jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:9094/hnlmnl_db
jdbc.username=infordev
jdbc.password=infordev
```

This is my servlet

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

but still getting error on connection..

Any help?

Thanks!

Here is the debug information

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: you must change it in mysql it self
check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360

Comment: @AmrBerag i changed its config in my.ini

Comment: @JamesAllen did you restarted the mysql service

Comment: Have you restarted, etc?

Comment: yes i have restarted it :( @roelofs

Comment: Is there a possibility to get more verbose debug information?

Comment: @roelofs i posted the the errors

Comment: Check the bind-address in mysql config. If it is commented uncomment it and try.

Comment: @JamesAllen Can you try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Any chance you have some kind of firewall in place?  Some antivirus firewalls will even impact local host.

Comment: Try to connect to the db using mysql client cli or mysql workbench using the configured hostname  and port if that works java code should also be able to connect.

Comment: This Port is used by another service? Has a firewall instead?

Comment: @uday may i know where is this located? i only know my.ini

Comment: @vts i already tried that bro.

Comment: i can connect via mysql workbench and java code using 3306 but when I change to 9094. the mysql workbench is the only that could connect @jitsonfire

Comment: port is free @GustavoAdolfo

Comment: @Pace already tried turning off firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused normally means that no service is listening on the server / port you are attempting to connect to:

- Check that the MySQL service is running.  If not, start it.
- Check that it is *actually* listening on 127.0.0.1:9094:

  - by using `netstat -a`,
  - by using the command line `mysql` tool or the workbench with the above IP / port
  - by attempting to connect to the above IP / port above using telnet or netcat or a similar tool.

If the service is running but not listening on that IP / port, then you need to fix the mysql server configuration.  Check the documentation.

If the service is running and listening on that IP / port, it suggests there is a networking problem; e.g. some weird firewalling.  (You should never need to do any firewalling on 127.0.0.1 ....)