# I can't connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My local pc have 2 server, it seems like phpmyadmin is only accessing the first server and not the other one. Is there a way to remove the first server and make the 2nd as a default?

EDIT:
this happened when i try to reconfigure my phpmyadmin using dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin, then after finshining the configuration, it created another server and now i can't connect to my primary server

Comment: You can config multiple DB server settings via `config.inc.php` in phpMyAdmin. Read their documentation for more information.

Comment: @Raptor this happened when i try to reconfigure my phpmyadmin using dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin, then after finshining the configuration, it created another server and now i can't connect to my primary server.

Comment: phpmyadmin has **no** relationship of DB server instance. It's just a client-side software for managing MySQL DB server, i.e. `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` won't create another DB instance. Double check your MySQL server login credentials.

Comment: @Raptor I know the username and password is correct because it was save in my project i am currently working, now even the project can't access the database.

Comment: Have you checked whether your MySQL server is running or not? Hint: use `netstat` or `telnet` to check.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if both server using the same port 3306.
If yes, you might want to change the second one to other port to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I'm really new in this thing, can you guide mo where to check this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360

Comment: locate my.ini or my.cnf and search port. remember to restart the service.

Comment: There's no port in the file. the only uncomment are

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

Comment: can you specify which system you've used and the respective directory structure.