# Python MySQLdb connect to Wamp server via custom port

Tags: python-3.x, wamp, wampserver, mysql-python, port80

I'm using Wamp Server's MySQL. I had to change port from 80 to 8000 by setting "Listens" in httpd.conf and also in httpd-vhosts. I have access to phpMyAdmin by browser (localhost:8000/...) but when I'm trying to connect by program like this:

```
 dbConn = MySQLdb.connect(host='192.168.1.110',port=8000, user='root', passwd='', db='test')
```

It freezes, and after exactly 60 seconds I'm getting error:

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

Before port change it was working fine.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
It works when I change port to 3306 and uncomment line `skip-grant-tables` in `my.ini`

Comment: You're problem is in your own statement. You can't run two different services off the same port. If phpmyadmin is on 8000 you can't run the sql server on 80000

Comment: @Kwright02 I have Apache on 8000 but MySQL runs on 3306 (Wamp server default). When I'm changing port to 3306 I get error :`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '192.168.1.110' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")`

Comment: Ok nevermind... I thought that's the same error where the port doesn't really exist. @Kwright02 Thanks for targeting me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you changed phpMyadmin port, but you didn't change mysql default port (3306).

See here 
[How to change the default port of mysql from 3306 to 3360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360)