# MYSQL installer console is not updating MYSQL Port

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MYSQL Server community edition 8.0.18 , using the MYSQLInstallerConsole.exe.
I want to listen the server at Port 3309 instead of default MYSQL port 3306. I have tried to used the following commands but MYSQL Server is installed and configured on port 3306. Can any body tell what is the problem.

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe community install server;8.0.18:*:port=3309;ServiceName=VUp  -silent
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this, I setup a custom service name, datadir and password. Change them to your liking but make sure it's not conflicting previous MySQL instance!

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe community install server;8.0.18:*:servertype=Server;servicename=MySql80189;port=3309;datadir="c:\MySQL\data80189";passwd=passFor80189 -silent
```

Looks like they had a bug with this at some point:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97252

Wondering if there is another one, in the worst case, could you install it to the default port (shutdown whatever is running at default port for moment) and change it post-installation in the **my.cfg** file?

[How to change the default port of mysql from 3306 to 3360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360)

Comment: I have tried the command you mentioned but mysql does not change port and password.

Comment: Is it ok for you to change it post installation?

Comment: Also is there a way to change the Default MYSQL server port from command line in windows

Comment: Yes, by producing your own custom my.cfg config and then on command line just copying it over the original.

Comment: If it is possible to change the Default MYSQL server port and password from command line after installation, i can also live with that option as well. Can you guide me in this direction as well.

Comment: I already answered the port question, you can produce your own my.cfg on your desktop, copy it to the server, and override the file just with a copy command on your command line. With changing password you could try ```mysql -u root -p```